# Handle multiple Ajax requests: ClearTimeout

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have elements coming from MySQL request.
They all have unique `id`'s also inserted as parameter into the onclick call function.

Every onlick, leads to searching data into database. This is done until database have send expected answer. When expected answer comes, function need to stop.

I don't know how to know, when expected data has arrived, how to stop this function.
I can't set `var x` to a different value and `var x is not defined`

```js
function search(id) {
 document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";
 var x = setInterval(function () {answer(id)}, 1000);
}

function answer(id) {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = id;
    /*
    AJAX request, looks for an anwser
    
     if(answer)
     {
     clearTimeout(x); // var x is not defined
     }
      
    */
}
```

```html
<div id="one" onclick="search('one');">
    click
</div>

<div id="two" onclick="search('two');">
    click
</div>

<div id="result">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object of intervals

```
var intervals = {};
function search(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";
    intervals[id] = setInterval(function () {answer(id)}, 1000);
}

function answer(id) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = id;
    /*
    AJAX request, looks for an anwser

     if(isAnswered)
     {
         clearTimeout(intervals[id]);
     }

    */
}
```

---

better would be use setTimeout and not worry about the intervals

```
function search(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";
    answer(id);
}

function answer(id) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = id;
    /*
    AJAX request, looks for an anwser

     if(!isAnswered)
     {
         window.setTimeout( function () { answer(id); }, 1000);
     }

    */
}
```

Comment: Your first answer worked, thank you! But I need to see if new data's coming every second. Why  EDIT?

Comment: *"But I need to see if new data's coming every second. Why "* HUH? what are you talking about...

Comment: Your first answer worked, thank you! But I need to see if new data's coming every second. Why edit?

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring X inside the function, and you cant access it outside..

Try something like this:

```js
var x; // here you will have a global variable
function search(id) {
     document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";
     return setInterval(function () {answer(id)}, 1000); // return the timeinterval ID
}

function answer(id) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = id;
    clearTimeout(x);
    /*
    AJAX request, looks for an anwser
    
     if(answer)
     {
     clearTimeout(x); // var x is not defined
     }
      
    */
}
```

```html
<div id="one" onclick="x = search('one');"> <!-- set X = the interval -->
    click
</div>

<div id="two" onclick="x = search('two');">
    click
</div>

<div id="result">
    
</div>
```

Comment: And you just created a new bug when they click on both divsby holding it in a global that they both overwrite.